# How to pass two values in onChange

Tags: javascript, dom

So, I have a 2 select tags and during the
onChange event of the second select tag; I want to pass the values of the 2 select tags

```
    <td>District:
    <div>
    <select name="district" id="district" onchange="getZone(this.value)">
    <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
    <?php
     include_once 'newcompute.php';
     $computation = new newcompute();
     echo $computation->getDistrict();
    ?>
    </select>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td>Barangay:&nbsp;
<div id="barangay" name="barangay">
    <select onchange="loadReport(barangay.value,district.value)">
<option>Select a Barangay</option>
<option value="ALL">ALL</option>
</select>
    </div>
</td>
    </tr>
```

So, I tried doing the onchange="loadReport(barangay.value,district.value)" but I only get 
a UNDEFINED value for district.value

How do I get loadReport to pass the current selected value of select tag district?

Comment: I would expect `barangay.value` to be `undefined` since `div` elements don't have a value. Shouldn't the ID be assigned to the `select` element? Also, don't rely on IDs becoming global variables, use `getElementById` to get a reference to an element.

Comment: I use the uhh.. `barangay div` to use `javascript innerhtml` to put new `select barangay tags and options` depending on the dropdown values of district and zone(which is not shown in the sample code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the other tag in the function itself. No need to pass it from here.

```
function loadReport(barangayValue)
{
    var district = document.getElementById('district');
    var districtValue = district.value;
    //Your stuff
}
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much for the uhh.. very fast reply!
can't upvote. 'need 15 reputation' it says.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<select onchange="loadReport(this.value,document.getElementById('district').value)">
<option>Select a Barangay</option>
<option value="ALL">ALL</option>
</select>
```

Comment: will try this later! but thanks! gtg. can't upvote. no reputation. :O

Comment: this one didn't work.. though i really do have codes that I borrowed from other thesis groups that used `loadReport(barangay.value,district.value,something.value,so on..)` that worked just don't know why it wouldn't work for my codes.